# submit form to two different places

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, formmail

I have a function called when a user clicks submit.

```
function submitForm() {
}
```

I want to be able to send the contents of the form to my email address via FormMail.pl, then once that happens do the default action which is to sent to paypal as this is an order form.

If found this code somewhere but it doesnt work

```
function submitForm() {
     var data = {};
    $("input").each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        if (typeof t.attr("name") == "string" && typeof t.val() == "string") {
            data[t.attr("name")] = t.val();
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        "type" : "POST",
        "url" : "cgi-bin/FormMail.pl",
        "data" : data,
        "dataType" : "json",
        "success" : function(data) {

            $(".submitLast").unbind("submit", onOrderFormSubmit)
                            .submit();

        },
        "error" : function(xhr, status) {
            console.log("failed to submit to FormMail (" + status + ")");
        }
    });

    return false;


}
```

I have also tried this

```
function submitForm() {
    alert("begin");
        $.post( 'http://www.spirecreativegroup.com/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl', $('form').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
            //data is the result from the script
            alert(data);
        });

        //Send data to the other script
        $.post( 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', $('form').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
            //data is the result from the script
            alert(data);
        });
}
```

On the second code i tried i get the begin alert but that is it.

I am not very experience but learning from your advice as i go. I would really appreciate some help or a point in the right direction.

Thank You,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

What you can do - you can submit your form to your script, this script will send email and then redirect user to paypal with `header('Location: ' . $paypal_url)`

Comment: I guess what i forgot to mention is that i have event.preventDefault() on submit as i have another function that needs to happen before it is ready to submit. Also where do i add your code? Thank you for getting back to me

Comment: That's a browsers security restriction, you can't send AJAX request to sites on different domains. So the script may looks like:
index.html

    <form action="send.php">.....</form>

send.php

    <?php
        mail('your@email.com', 'Subject', 'Body');
        header('Location: paypal.com?' . $compiled_variables);
    ?>